# Snowflake Unable to get the hierarchy columns values

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I have below table from which i am trying to get the correspondent manager name against the employee

```
TITLE                           EMPLOYEE_ID   MANAGER_ID
President                         1 
Vice President Engineering        10             1
Programmer                        100            10
QA Engineer                       101            10
Vice President HR                 20             1
Health Insurance Analyst          200            20
```

i used below hierarchy query to get the result

```
select employee_id, manager_id, title,  prior report_title
  from employees
    start with title = 'President'
    connect by
      manager_id = prior employee_id
  order by employee_id;
```

But result not returning as i expected

## Expected:

```
EMPLOYEE_ID   MANAGER_ID    title                         report_title
  10             1          Vice President Engineering    President
```

Can anyone help on this?

Comment: Please update your question to show some sample data. What result are you getting from your query if it is not the result you expect?

Comment: PRIOR is only supported in the CONNECT BY clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use a recursive CTE, you can get the output you want.

```
with emptree as
(select employee_id, title, manager_id, null as report_title
 from employees
 where manager_id is null
 union all
 select employees.employee_id, employees.title, employees.manager_id, emptree.title
  from employees
  join emptree
  on employees.manager_id = emptree.employee_id
)
select employee_id, manager_id, title, report_title
from emptree
order by employee_id;
```

| EMPLOYEE_ID | MANAGER_ID | TITLE | REPORT_TITLE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | NULL | President |  |
| 10 | 1 | Vice President Engineering | President |
| 20 | 1 | Vice President HR | President |
| 100 | 10 | Programmer | Vice President Engineering |
| 101 | 10 | QA Engineer | Vice President Engineering |
| 200 | 20 | Health Insurance Analyst | Vice President HR |